# How to get a file in order to upload it to server (ember-paper)

Tags: ember.js

Using ember-paper I tried to upload a file (image) to a server (expressJS) but I can't get the file.

```
#template.hbs
{{paper-input
  type="file"
  file=file
  onChange=(action (mut file))
}}
{{#paper-button onClick=(action 'submit')}}submit{{/paper-button}}

#controller.js
actions: {
  submit() {
    console.log(this.get('file'));
  }
}
```

Tried several combinations but always got 'undefined'.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the `onChange` method is never called. `onChange` is linked to the HTML input attribute `oninput` which is not supported for input type `file`.

I spoke with Miguel about the fix.